# How to add a text label to a tableview in the center?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I use the code below:

```
label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 44)];
label.center = self.tableView.center;
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.text=NSLocalizedString(@"Network Not Reachable", nil);
[self.tableView addSubview:label];
```

But I want the label located in the center of the light gray lines.
You could see the Calendar's screenshot.

[image: Compare]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with below one.

```
float assumedCellHeight = 44;
float hh = self.tableView.bounds.size.height;
int num = (hh / assumedCellHeight)/2;

num = (num % 2 == 0)?num:num-1;

float yy = assumedCellHeight*num;

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yy, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, assumedCellHeight)];
// label.center = self.tableView.center;
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.text=NSLocalizedString(@"Network Not Reachable", nil);
[self.tableView addSubview:label];
```

It's working for me.

Thanks.